# How to send email using SMTP and connected to proxy in PHP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to send email via windstream.net webmail
I already setup the mailer with SMTP Using [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) 
but worked in localhost and didnt work on the host
but I got the problem windstream allow only for US IP to send emails
so I want to connect with proxy before send email

I tried on USA C-panel free hosting and worked and didn't work on my Web Host because it is from UK and I cant change the cpanel but I can put proxy to the cpanel to use it paid and I think it will work perfect I tried it on localhost when I opened VPN

```php
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.windstream.net";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "user@windstream.net";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = "465";                     
$mail->setFrom('user@windstream.net', 'Windstream');
$mail->addReplyTo('user@windstream.net', 'Windstream');
$mail->addAddress('user@windstream.net');
$mail->isHTML(false);
$bodyContent = 'Message Sent';
$mail->Subject = 'Script test';
$mail->Body    = $bodyContent;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message Sent';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message Failed';
}
?>
```

Comment: surely your web host has a mail server?

Comment: A proxy or a VPN should be transparent to the SMTP client - so it doesn't have to know.